# How to filter Spring's Page<Entity> object using java8's filter() and return Page<Entity>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-8

I am calling database with custom query dsl and getting a `Page<Product>` with `findAll()` call to hibernate. I have a filter named `filterValidProducts` that calls an external service and would filter the elements from `Page<Product>` based on response from external service. I am not able to find proper collector that will hold filtered `Page<Product>` .

What I notice is if I pass some page size it is restricting the response to that page size and I am not actually able to get expected values for `totalElements` when I pass `size` to my filter.

I tried the following code :-

```
public ResponseWrapper<Product> listProducts(ProductFilter productFilter){
    Page<Product> entityPage = productDAO.list(productFilter);
    List<ProductEntity> productEntityList = entityPage.getContent().stream()
                        .filter(filterValidProducts)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(productFilter.getPage(), 
productFilter.size());
    Page<ProductEntity> productEntityFiltered=
            new PageImpl<>(productEntityList , pageable, productEntityList .size());
    ResponseWrapper<Product> responseWrapper =
            productTransformer.transformPage(productEntityFiltered, productFilter);

    return responseWrapper;
}
```

This is how `ProductFilter` looks like

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ProductFilter {
    private Long clientId;
    private Integer page;
    private Integer size;
    private Long productId;
    private ProductType productType;
}
```

I want to filter on `Page<Product>` without converting it to `List<ProductEntity>`

The `totalElements` from `entityPage` is 168. Default size for `Pageable` is 25.

**Actual:**

After filtering the `productEntityList` it has 14 `totalElements`.

If I query with size for `Pageble` as 3, after filtering the `productEntityList` has 3 elements.

**Expected:**

If I query with size for `Pageble` as 3, the `totalElements` should still be 14 with multiple pages each with size 3.

I feel if I am able to apply the function `filterValidProducts` on `entityPage` and properly collect to `Page<Product>` updated `totalElements` based on filter then this problem would be solved.

Thanks for reading so far.

Comment: `totalElements` is the number of elements you can get but the actual number of elements you got in the first query is 25 in default. If you need to get more, I think you should query all elements or do some SQL operations.

Comment: @TranNgocKhoa I dont need to get more more, i just need to be able to apply the filter on Page< Product > to reduce and also updating the totalElements based on the filter. Also the filter that I apply is an external service so I cannot add any queryDSL to the predicate.

Comment: Could you provide `ProductFilter` code?

Comment: Just did @TranNgocKhoa